# Getting Undefined index error

Tags: php

Im getting the following error: Notice:undefined index:done 
   please advise what is wrong

```
 <?php
        if($_Get['done']==1 $msg = "Account details saved";

 ?>
```

Comment: Do `print_r($_GET)` and see if you have `done` key present in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if the key exists, then the comparison to `1`.

```
if (isset($_GET['done']) && $_GET['done'] == 1) {
    $msg = '...';
}
```